# How to use broadcast reciever to get sent intent from smsmanager (nativescript)

Tags: javascript, android, broadcastreceiver, nativescript, android-pendingintent

I am using nativescript to build an app that will programmatically send a pre-built text to multiple preset parties in case of emergency.

I have an array of phone numbers and want to iterate over each one, using SMSmanager to send the text and the sentIntent argument [seen in android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#getDefault()) to verify that the text was sent before moving on to the next array item.

I have created the pendingIntent variable to pass into "sms.sendTextMessage" as follows:

```
var sms = android.telephony.SmsManager.getDefault();
var utils = require("utils/utils");

//Gets application's current state
var context = utils.ad.getApplicationContext();
//Create a replica of Android's intent object
var intent = new android.content.Intent(context, com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.class);

//Create a replica of Android's pendingIntent object using context and intent
var pendingIntent = android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, intent, android.app.PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

I then send the text, passing in the pending intent var:

```
sms.sendTextMessage("5555555555", null, "hello", pendingIntent, null);
```

I then attempt to make a basic broadcast receiver using the information I found in the [nativescript docs](http://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/application#registering-a-broadcast-receiver-android) which should just log something to the console when it recieves the expected data.

```
app.android.registerBroadcastReceiver(pendingIntent, function() {
        console.log("@@@@@ text sent @@@@@");
    });
```

The problem is: nothing happens. I'd expect to get ""@@@@@ text sent @@@@@" logged to the console. I've googled a lot and am thinking maybe I need to add something about this broadcast reciever in the manifest, or perhaps my implimentation is wrong somewhere, but this is my first crack at an android app and I'm at a bit of a loss. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't do NativeScript, but if you're registering a Receiver at runtime, you need to send it an implicit `Intent`; i.e., an `Intent` instantiated with a unique, arbitrary `String` action argument, rather than a `Context` and `Class`. Then, you need to register the Receiver for that `String` action, and it looks like, to do that, the action should be the first argument in your `registerBroadcastReceiver()` call, rather than `pendingIntent` . And your `PendingIntent` needs to be obtained with `getBroadcast()`, instead of `getActivity()`.

Comment: Hey this helped me find the solutions :) thanks! I'm posing the code that worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question here in case anyone else runs into this.

The code that worked is:

```
    var app = require("application");
    var utils = require("utils/utils");
    var context = utils.ad.getApplicationContext();
    var sms = android.telephony.SmsManager.getDefault();

    var SendMessages = {

        init: function() {
                var id = "messageSent";
                this.sendText(id, this.pendingIntent(id));
        },

        sendText: function(id, pendingIntent) {
            sms.sendTextMessage("5555555555", null, "Hello :)", pendingIntent, null);
            this.broadcastReceiver(id, function() {
                console.log("$$$$$ text sent $$$$$");
            });
        },

        pendingIntent: function(id) {
            var intent = new android.content.Intent(id);
            return android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        },

        broadcastReceiver: function(id, callback) {
            app.android.registerBroadcastReceiver(id, function() {
                callback();
            });
        }

    };

module.exports = SendMessages;
```

To explain: it seems as @Mike M mentioned each intent object needs some string as an id.

Then to make the "pendingIntent" object, again as @Mike M. mentioned I needed to hook to "getBroadcast" method, then I needed to pass pending intent the app context as the first argument, then 0, then the intent object with the id.

The pending intent then is receivable in a simple broadcast receiver function by simply passing the intent id as the first argument and the callback as the second. I've tested and it's working perfectly.

Comment: No, I said the first argument to `registerBroadcastReceiver()` should be the action, not the `PendingIntent`, which is exactly what you're doing. The only change I suggested to the `PendingIntent` itself was to obtain it with `getBroadcast()`. The `Intent` instantiation is where I said not to pass the `Context`. Also, the action doesn't have to be random. It just needs to be what you're registering the Receiver for.

Comment: You're right - I have updated my answer to reflect this and refactored the code. Thanks again. I spent nearly 4 hours researching the android API docs and your help pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Yeah, the reason I said "unique, arbitrary" was to try to say that it could be pretty much anything you want, so long as it's not an action that already means something else, that other apps might be listening for. I should've explained that better. The usual way to ensure uniqueness for that is to prepend your app/package name to the action description. Anyhoo, sorry if I came off a little blunt in my last comment. SO's been a little frustrating today. :) Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Following is a simplified version, no bs code approach to what you need to make it run. You need permissions and to make sure the user accepts those permissions. This is also one of the two ways (this one is the `context-registered receiver` way) to create a broadcast receiver, read more about both types here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#receiving-broadcasts

Info on registering broadcast receiver: [https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/*application*.androidapplication.html#registerbroadcastreceiver](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_application_.androidapplication.html#registerbroadcastreceiver)

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="__PACKAGE__"
    android:versionCode="10000"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <!-- ...more code -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

    <!-- ...more code -->

</manifest>
```

`JavaScript`:

```
import * as application from 'tns-core-modules/application';
import * as platform from 'tns-core-modules/platform';
import * as utils from 'tns-core-modules/utils/utils';
import * as permissions from 'nativescript-permissions';

// ...more code

try {
    await permissions.requestPermission(
        android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS,
        'Need to send.'
    );
    console.log('SEND_SMS permission accepted.');

    const text = 'Herro.';
    const mobileNumber = '55555555';
    const intentFilter = 'something_here';
    const context = utils.ad.getApplicationContext();
    const intent = new android.content.Intent(intentFilter);
    const pendingIntent = android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    const sms = android.telephony.SmsManager.getDefault();
    application.android.registerBroadcastReceiver(intentFilter, function() {
        console.log(`Text has been sent: ${text}`);
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Sending text.');
        sms.sendTextMessage(mobileNumber, null, text, pendingIntent, null);
    }, 5000);
} catch (error) {
    console.log('Permission error:', error);
}
```

The code above is created inside the activity and uses the main ui thread. This means that if the user exits the activity, the broadcast receiver will linger in limbo and android can destroy it.